# Makefile to CodeLite

Tags: makefile, codelite

How can I convert a Makefile-based project into a CodeLite project?

Comment: @Claudio: I have reworded the question, could you please reconsider taking it off hold?

Comment: @EdChum: I have reworded the question, could you please reconsider taking it off hold?

Comment: Useful question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These steps will allow you to use an existing source files with an existing `Makefile` within CodeLite:

- Create a new workspace
- Create a new project, in the `New Project` wizard, Expand the `Others` entry and select `Custom Makefile` and complete the wizard. As a good practice, make sure you place the project location in the root folder of your source files.
- Once the newly project is added to the workspace, right click it and select `Import files from directory` and select the directories you want to import.

Now, you will need to update the `Build` options (so when hitting `F7` or right clicking on the project and selecting `build` your Makefile is called)

- Right click on the project and select `Settings`
- In the project dialog that shows, select `Customize->Custom Build`
- Make sure the `Enable custom build` is ON (should be if you selected the `Custom Makefile` template from above)
- You can edit the various targets (e.g. `Build`, `Clean` etc or add new ones)

Once the build is all setup, you will need to make sure that you can `Run` / `Debug` your binaries:

- Right click on the project and select `Settings`
- Select the `General` tab
- Under `Execution` section, make sure that the `Executable to Run / Debug` is pointing to your binary

Comment: Thank you!!! Finally got live debugging via Codelite for my custom makefile.

Answer (score -1):

I think I found one [here](https://wiki.codelite.org/pmwiki.php/Main/CustomMakefiles).
Further information, examples, etc would be useful too.